# how i can call method of other activity through intent?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I am new in Android and I want to call method of another `Activity` in Android. Can you please tell me how I can call the method of other activity please? I want to call a method in `Mechanics` class - how can I call it through `Intent`?

```
switch(subject)
              {
              case 0:
                  Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Mechanics.class);
                  startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                  break;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass additional parameters via the intent. The new activity can then check those and call the intended method.

You want to look up the `putSomething` methods of [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

Comment: hii Sir i have a method in Mechanics class so how can i call it?

Comment: Do something like this: in the `Activity` which calls the `Mechanics` one, do a `myIntent.putString`, or whatever parameters you need to pass, and on the `onCreate` method of `Mechanics` check if any parameter was passed, and let the `onCreate` of `Mechanics` actually call the method you want called